# Are lists immutable in python? And are they passed value in a function?

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing, immutability

```
def threshold(the_list,thresholding_value,upper_val,lower_value):
    ret_list=list(the_list)
    for each_item in ret_list:
        if each_item <= thresholding_value:
            each_item=lower_value
        else:
            each_item=upper_val
    return ret_list

temp=[-1,2,5,3,-1,5,32,-6]
ttt=r.threshold(temp,0,1,0)
```

after exection I am still getting the value of list same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are not immutable, but when you loop over one, the loop control variable gets a copy of each item; it's not an alias for it.  So changing it doesn't affect the list.

A more Pythonic way to do this would be a list comprehension returning the new list:

```
def threshold(the_list, threshold, upper, lower):
  return [lower if item <= threshold else upper for item in the_list]

threshold([-1,2,5,3,-1,5,32,-6],0,1,0)
# => [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: if the list is an attribute of a class, and i change this attribute during looping over it - changing does affect the list

Comment: @neumlouno - whether the list is an attribute or not doesn't matter, and of course if you change the list variable or attribute or whatever it will change. The point here is that if you do a `for var in (any list expression here):`, then modifying `var` in the body of that loop will not affect the list being looped over at all.

Answer (score 1):

each_item is just a local variable which has its value overriden with the `=` operator. Assigning a value to it won't affect the original list. Instead, you could create a new list and fill it up before returning it:

```
def threshold(the_list, thresholding_value, upper_val, lower_val):
    ret_list = list()
    for each_item in the_list:
        if each_item <= thresholding_value:
            ret_list.append(lower_val)
        else:
            ret_list.append(upper_val)
    return ret_list
```

You could also shorten this code significantly by using list comprehensions:

```
def threshold(the_list, thresholding_value, upper_val, lower_val):
    return [lower_val if x <= thresholding_value else upper_val for x in the_list]
```

Comment: Okay thanks alot for the answer.

I thought this iteration variable works as we use in general for Java or C. Actually I am new for python, can you plz explain the meaning of return statement.

Comment: In the second example? This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's an easy way to define new lists without going through the robustness of writing big ol' loops.

Comment: List comprehensions visually explained: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 0):

Lists are most definitely mutable. What happens is you iterate over the list, with each element copied to `each_item` in turn. What happens to each_item is not relevant to the list, as it is just a temp variable to hold your value, not a pointer.

Representing each_item as a 1-element list or a class would fix your issue, but the whole approach is not how it is usually done in python: why create a copy of list when you can create an empty list for return value and add elements as you go?